# Running a code on server A but getting an API connection error originating from server

Tags: python, flask, connectionexception

I am running a code from server A. Below is the error message. The error is tracing back to this line of code `api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4657/embeddings'` every time, which is think is from a different server B. What should I do to remove this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1294, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1340, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1289, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1048, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f374f413650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 799, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4657): Max retries exceeded with url: /embeddings (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f374f413650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/pritika/EaseMyTrip/Chat/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from INTENT.intent import IntentDetector
  File "/root/pritika/EaseMyTrip/Chat/INTENT/intent.py", line 233, in <module>
    top_5 = intent.get_top_sentence_candidates("This is the first sentence.")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/EaseMyTrip/Chat/INTENT/intent.py", line 56, in get_top_sentence_candidates
    input_embedding = self.get_input_embedding_from_api(input_sentence)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/EaseMyTrip/Chat/INTENT/intent.py", line 42, in get_input_embedding_from_api
    response = requests.post(api_url, json={'texts': input_sentence})
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4657): Max retries exceeded with url: /embeddings (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f374f413650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I am running a code from server A. Below is the error message. The error is tracing back to this line of code `api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4657/embeddings'` every time, which is think is from a different server B. What should I do to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is the "loopback" or "localhost" address - it's how a system can use the Internet Protocol to refer to itself. (The English words "I", "me", "my", and "mine" are similar: the person using those words is always referring to themselves, or to something associated with themselves.)

Your code here is running on Server A and attempting to connect to Server A - *not Server B*. It looks like there's nothing listening on port 4657 on Server A's loopback address; should there be?

Comment: there is something on port 4657 and it is working fine when i am running the same code on server B. What changes do i need to do while running the code on server A?

Answer (score 0):

**127.0.0.1 IP address refers to the local IP address** on which the code runs on. So, The problem is that Server A (where you run your code) differs from where the API exists. **You have to set the IP address of Server B** (or the server that API runs on).

Using local addresses such as 127.0.0.1/, 0.0.0.0/, or localhost/ only works when you want to access an API that exists on the same server that the code runs. But, **to access an API in a different server, you have to use the server IP address**. Something like:

```
api_url = 'http://192.158.1.38:4657/embeddings'
api_url = 'http://{SERVER_IP}:4657/embeddings'
```